# Pandas indexing by integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Coming from Excel background, I find indexes so confusing in code.

Typically I'll make something an index that I feel should be one, then lose the functionality I would have had when it was a column.

I've a df with 4 digit years from 2015 to 2113 as the index. If i call a for loop on the index they are class type int (shouldn't matter for my purposes).

I then want to take a cut that's just 2020, so I do

`df[df.index==2020]` and it returns a blank df where there is data to return

If i do `df.loc[2020]` it says it can't do label indexing on ints

I just want to slice the data by years (so I can say just give me 2020 onward for example)

What am I doing wrong? Feel like I'm missing something fundamental?

I created a mock df to reproduce the problem for the question but that works fine.

If I do a for loop on the index of both the problem df and the example one they both return class int for each row

If I do `example_df.index` though it returns

```
Int64Index(2019,2020,2021, dtype='int64', name='Yr')
```

If I do the same on the problem df, it returns

```
Index(['2019','2020','2021'],dtype='object')
```

The above look like strings to me, but the loop says they are int?

Original problem index comes from Excel with set_index, so i can't produce an example here.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to set a column as index, you can just leave it as a numbered index which would allow you to keep the functionality of that column. I rarely set indexes

Answer (score 1):

On the `problem df`, indeed the index's data type is string.

```py
Index(['2019','2020','2021'],dtype='object')
```

When you write

```py
df[df.index==2020]
```

A blank result is expected because you search for int 2020 not string '2020'.

Then, in code

```py
df.loc[2020]
```

Is a wrong code for searching some data with some condition. `loc` is used to slice column and row, not to search a row by some condition like what you wanted to do.

So the code

```py
df[df.index==2020]
```

is the most right answer, but first you need to change the datatype of your index column first.

```py
df.index= [int(i) for i in df.index]
```

Comment: `.loc` can be also used to select a row by its index value, so `df.loc[2020]` would be a valid solution as well if `df` had an integer index. For the conversion, you can also use `df.index = df.index.astype(int)`.